# Ionic component not saving data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, components

I have developed multiple components and i want to use in my page.
let say component1,component2 and component3

when i load my page i want only one component to be active at a time so i wrote this code in my **page.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="bgColor">


    <div *ngIf="selectdPageNo == '1'">
        <component1></component1>
    </div> 

    <div *ngIf="selectdPageNo == '2'">
        <component2></component2> 
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="selectdPageNo == '3'">
        <component3></component3>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

it is working properly(On each component there are few input fields and next button is present. when i click on next button it loads next component.)

Problem is when i load new component and comes back to previous component data which i have filled on previous gets lost. how do i preserved my data?
or what wrong i am doing?

***Please help and thanks in advance!***

Comment: Can you please try with hidden instead of ngIf? I think that should work because hidden just hide that html and ngIf remove html from dom so

Comment: can you help me to get syntax to write in html ionic

Comment: Ok Post please check and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below code.

```
<ion-content padding class="bgColor">
    <div [hidden]="selectdPageNo == '1'">
        <component1></component1>
    </div> 

    <div [hidden]="selectdPageNo == '2'">
        <component2></component2> 
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="selectdPageNo == '3'">
        <component3></component3>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

You have to use `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf` because hidden is just hide html in dom and ngIf remove html from dom so when you switch to next page previous html if removed.

Comment: It got worked after writing [hidden]="selectdPageNo != '1'"

Comment: Yes you have use != with hidden. Please upvote and accept if possible